# Showing a group formed from $Q_8$ is a subring of $M(2,C)$, has unity, and is a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

The quaternion group $Q_8$ is the group which consists of the following eight matrices in $M(2, C):Q_8 = \{I, A, A^2, A^3, B, BA, BA^2, BA^3\}$, where:

$$
       I = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
       A = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
       -1 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
       B = \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & i \\
       i & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $H = \{aI + bBA^3 + cA + dB; a, b, c, d ∈ R \}$. Prove the following:

a). $H$ is a subring of $M(2, C)$;

b). $H$ has unity;

c). $H$ is a division ring.

From my understanding:

For a) I need to show that $H \subset M(2,C)$ and that $H$ is closed under addition and multiplication, has a $0$ element and an additive inverse.

For b) I need to find a multiplicative identity in $H$.

For c) I need to show that for every element in $H$, there exists a unique multiplicative inverse such that the product of each element and its inverse equals the unit element.

I'm having a lot of trouble getting started with this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Travis sorry about that. Wasn't thinking when I wrote the title. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a) it will suffice to show $H$ is closed under multiplication, and for $Q,Q' \in H$, that $Q-Q' \in H$.

Showing $Q-Q' \in H$ is pretty easy, to show $H$ is closed under multiplication, note that $A,B$ and $BA^3$, are all of the form:

$\begin{bmatrix}z&w\\-\overline{w}&\overline{z}\end{bmatrix}$, for some $z,w \in \Bbb C$, and thus every $Q \in H$ is of that form.

Moreover, given a matrix of such form, write it as an element of $H$ (just think about it for a little while).

Show that matrices of this form are likewise closed under multiplication.

For b) the unity of $H$ ought to be *obvious*.

For c), if:

$Q = aI + b(BA^3) + cA + dB$, define:

$Q^{\ast} = aI - b(BA^3) - cA - dB$.

Show $QQ^{\ast} \in \Bbb RI$ (that is the (real) coordinates of $BA^3,A$ and $B$ are $0$). Why is this helpful?

Comment: For a I worked out what matrix $H$ actually is. I did what you said but for my own reference, why don't we have to show the other stuff I mentioned? 

So for b) I figured it would be just $I$. 

c) I'm still working out what you said.

Comment: It's the "one-step subgroup test", applied to the additive group of $M(2,\Bbb C)$-closure under subtraction proves additive closure, the inclusion of the additive identity, and the inclusion of additive inverses "all at once".